# Run application with GUI using PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis

I'm trying to run several applications with the php 'exec' and 'popen'-command.

A simple example:

```
pclose(popen("start /B notepad", "r"));
```

or:

```
exec("start notepad");
```

The process I want to start is displayed in the Task Manager, but the GUI doesn't show up.

I already allowed the IIS World Wide Web Publishing-service to interact with the Desktop.

Could anyone give me any help on how to get this working?